# Comparing data from complex set of parent child tables

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, parent-child

I have two Oracle DB schemas and each schema has following two tables:

1) Table T1 with columns: child_id, parent_id, type
2) Table T2 with columns: id, attribute, value

How can I compare data stored in these two schemas and find out any mismatches (in best possible way)? The data can be like this:

```
T1:  
1, NULL, 'Fruit'  
2, 1, 'Orange'  
3, 1, 'Apple'  
4, 3, 'Gala'

T2:  
1, 'Company Name', 'ABC'  
1, 'Dept', 'Fruits'  
2, 'name', 'XX Oranges'
2, 'color', 'Orange'
2, 'taste', 'Sweet'
3, 'name', 'YY Apples'
3, 'color', 'Red'
4, 'taste', 'Very Sweet'
```

The data can be stored up to any level in hierarchy and I want to find out if there is any mismatch e.g. 'Gala' 'Apples' are not 'Very Sweet' in other schema.

The ids can be different in these two schemas.

Comment: Can you show us the output you expect?

Comment: Yeah, and where are you expecting to store it?

Comment: Any kind of output is fine as long as it shows the differences. It can be printed on screen or can be flat file or can be another table. I know this is a fairly complex issue but any hints will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your schemas are called 'schema1' and 'schema2', you can search for mismatches using set operators. any rows returned by this query represent differences between the two schemas:

```
(
  SELECT * FROM schema1.t1
  MINUS
  SELECT * FROM schema2.t1
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT * FROM schema2.t1
  MINUS
  SELECT * FROM schema1.t1
);
```

the first of these mini-queries gives you all the rows found in schema1.t1 that aren't in schema2.t1, and the second gives you those from schema2.t1 that aren't in schema1.t1 - putting the two together with UNION ALL gives you all the mismatches. you may find it clearer to run the queries independently, depending on what you want.

obviously just substitute 't2' for 't1' in the above to see differences for the other table.

Comment: One thing I didnt mention is that the ids can be different in these two schemas.